# Write text to new tab in VS Code programmatically

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to generate summary text and show it somehow. I would be glad to hear about any way to achieve it, however I think that it might be possible to open new tab and write everything there. How can I open new tab and write some text into it? Something like some packages shows release notes in separate tab after install/update. Or maybe there is other way to show quite a lot of text?

Comment: This is not exactly what you are asking, but you can write your text to a file on disk and then open it with API call. Or just open an existing file using the same method (e.g. if this is a static release notes file)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest way is probably to just write into new `Untitled` file:

```typescript
async function openInUntitled(content: string, language?: string) {
    const document = await vscode.workspace.openTextDocument({
        language,
        content,
    });
    vscode.window.showTextDocument(document);
}

openInUntitled('just\ntext');
openInUntitled('* list item', 'markdown');
```